# How to get the DropDown selected value in controller in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-select

Hi all i have to get the selected value from dropdown into my post method in controller ..how can i do this

here is my controller

```
       [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult AddNew()
    {          
        ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(List(), "RoleID", "RoleName");           
        return View();
    }
    //
    //Geting All Roles In a GetRoles()/
    //
    public List<ResourceModel> List()
      {
          var roles = new List<ResourceModel>();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LMIT-0039;Initial Catalog=BugTracker;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("Select GroupId,EmplopyeeRole from  EmployeeGroup", conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {                                
            var model = new ResourceModel();
            model.RoleId = Convert.ToInt16(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["GroupId"]);
            model.RoleName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["EmplopyeeRole"].ToString();               
            roles.Add(model);
        }
          conn.Close();
          return roles ;
      }

    //
    //To perform the AddNew Logic..i.e it adds a new employee to DB/
    //
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult AddNew(ResourceModel model)
    {
        // var modelList = new List<ProjectModel>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LMIT-0039;Initial Catalog=BugTracker;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand insertcommande = new SqlCommand("InsertEmplyoee", conn);
            insertcommande.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            insertcommande.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.EmployeeName;
            insertcommande.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeEmailId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.EmployeeEmailId;
            insertcommande.Parameters.Add("@EmployeePassword", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.EmployeePassword;
            insertcommande.Parameters.Add("@GroupName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.RoleName;
            insertcommande.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

now i want to get the selected value @GroupName Parameter in my postmethod...can any one help how to do thi

this is my html

```
  <%:Html.DropDownList("Roles")%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have your POST action take a view model, or add another parameter to it that will hold the selected value:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult AddNew(ResourceModel model, string roles)
```

And don't forget to repopulate the `ViewBag.Roles` in your POST action the same way you did in your GET action if you intend to redisplay the same view.

Comment: the `roles` parameter should be `int`. Isn't it?

Comment: That will depend on what type is used in the database. Could also be a Guid or something. Only the OP knows this and since he hasn't provided this information in his question I assumed string because this will map with any type.

Comment: yes the parameter is a string....i dnt get what u said  to do with the ViewBage.Roles,can u expalin me how to do it

Comment: i have to get it at @GroupName parameter in my method

Comment: Oh, I am sorry I did not notice. Actually, I saw another problem by Anil of same domain where `roles` was specified to be `int`. But here it is not specified. Whatever, it will always map to `string` of course.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov how can i get the value in string Roles

Comment: @anilkumar: You still do not get the value? Remember, you have to put the `<%:Html.DropDownList("Roles")%>` inside the form in your view.

Comment: @Mohayemin i have the values in my dropdown now i have to retrieve them in my controller

Comment: The selected value will be passed in the `roles` argument that your POST controller action need to take.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Request.Form["Roles"]` in your controller action.. but maybe a better solution is creating a new view model for the page and you can use `Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleID, rolesSelectList)` or whatever.. and the value will be automatically bound to your model in the udpate method:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] 
    public ActionResult AddNew(ResourceModel model)
```